# ASP.NET Checkbox doesn't know what state it should be in

Tags: asp.net, html

One interesting phenomenon I've noted today is that if a checkbox input is **not** checked, it is not included in the postback variables; no "_xyzcheckbox : off" corresponds with the "_xyzcheckbox: on" alternative (when 'checked').

This leads to an issue of storing check state if the checkbox is hidden on the server and then revealed later; the Checkbox does not know whether or not it is simply hidden (not in the DOM) or if it is being unchecked based on the postback that the browser sends back to the server, as the postback includes no reference to the checkbox if it is unchecked.

I am having an issue where I need to hide a checkbox (using .Visible = false on a parent of the checkbox) and show it depending on the users input, but the state cannot be persisted because of the aforementioned issue.

Has anyone else come across this issue? How have you solved it or gotten around it?

Note: The most obvious answer his hiding the checkbox on the client (setting display: none), this isn't an option though as we're trying to reduce the markup on the page so that postbacks are smaller.

Thanks for the feedback thus far.

Thanks :)

Comment: Shouldn't the state be persisted in viewstate?

Comment: @Ek0nomik Nope, try it yourself.


James Johnson Yeah, that's what I thought.. but how is an IPostBackDataHandler supposed to know if the user is changing the value (by unchecking it) or the control simply hasn't been rendered? The OnCheckChanged event will be fired when any postback comes in without that unique ID, and set the box back to unchecked.

Comment: Regarding page size: simply using compression is going to have a much larger impact than removing what amounts to 40 maybe 50 bytes?  And if you have compression turned on that 40+ bytes might only really be 5.  Unless we're talking millions of page views a day it's not going to add up to be worth your time.

Comment: Also, if this is a wide scale thing, then I'd recommend simply breaking the pages down into content that can be loaded dynamically via ajax as necessary on the client.

Comment: @Chris Lively Thanks Chris,

We are actually using GZIP transport compression as well as Viewstate compression; the components of the page that are being collapsed/hidden are actually quite large, so it's not just hiding/showing individual checkboxes, it's hiding/showing large sections of the page which **contain** checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use .Visible (which removes the checkbox from the emitted markup, and therefore no chance of it being in a POST back), why not apply a CSS class to it?

The CSS could be as follows:

```
input.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

In your ASP.NET page simply set the CssClass property:

```
MyCheckbox.CssClass = "hidden";
```

And you should be fine.

Comment: That would be nice, but in fact the whole reason for this becoming an issue in the first place is because we're optimizing the page, and in order to do that we have to remove it from the DOM entirely; the page used to store everything on the client side and hide and show things through javascript, but the page could get over 2 mb in size, depending on how much info the user filled in, now that we've started hiding things on the server side, the markup size has been reduced to something like 12 kb to represent that same page (with all the nodes collapsed)

Comment: OK - perhaps include that detail in the question to avoid further similar answers.

Answer (score 0):

In the mark-up, you can default `selected = "false"`.

In the code-behind, you can determine the state by `mycheckbox.checked`, which will either return `true` or `false`.